Inherit Serializer and Make Fields Render with HiddenInput
I am reusing a serializer from a third party library.
I define import and define the serializer like this to reset the to_representation() method:
class ExtendedSerializer(ThirdPartySerializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value

My view fills the serializer with data and calls is_valid():
serializer = ExtendedSerializer(
    data={"key":"value"}
)
serializer.is_valid()

My template renders it like this:
{% render_form serializer template_pack='rest_framework/inline' %}

This is great and lets me reuse a small portion of the API without creating a lot of forms to duplicate the serializer logic. However, I want the data to be rendered using the form.HiddenInput (or someway that I can generically output the rendered inputs as type="hidden").
If this was a Django form I could do this:
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['awesomefield'].widget = forms.MultipleHiddenInput()

I am rusty with drf - what is analogous for serializers?
Thanks!

Worked my way through the serializer source. Looks like this is how you do it:
class ExtendedSerializer(ThirdPartySerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.style = {'base_template': 'input.html', 'input_type': 'hidden'}
    
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value

To remove label output you also need to add a custom template pack:
{% render_form serializer template_pack='path/to/custom/templates/dir' %}

A minimal example is as follows:
path/to/custom/templates/dir/form.html:
{% extends 'rest_framework/inline/form.html' %}

path/to/custom/templates/dir/input.html:
<input name="{{ field.name }}" type="{{ style.input_type }}" {% if field.value is not None %}value="{{ field.value }}"{% endif %}>

You can reference https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/3.15.1/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/inline for more detail.
